# Using a walrus operator in if statement does not work

Tags: python, walrus-operator

I have a simple function that should output a prefix based on a pattern or `None` if it does not match. Trying to do a walrus it does not seem to work. Any idea?

```
import re

def get_prefix(name):
    if m := re.match(f'^.+(\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d\d\d)$', name) is not None:
        return m.group(3) + m.group(2) + m.group(1)

get_prefix('abc 10-12-2020')
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in get_prefix
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: You're setting `m` to `re.match(f'^.+(\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d\d\d)$', name) is not None`, which is a boolean. Get rid of `is not None`.

Comment: `is not None` is redundant anyway, because `re.match` always returns either a (non-falsy) match object or `None`.

Comment: @bereal It's theoretically faster to check `is None` since it compares the identities directly instead of having to call `__bool__()`. Also it's more explicit and, according to PEP-8, more Pythonic.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen PEP-8 refers to the cases when an accepted value can be Falsy. Which is not the case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're setting `m` to `re.match(f'^.+(\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d\d\d)$', name) is not None`, which is a boolean.

You probably mean

```
if (m := re.match(f'^.+(\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d\d\d)$', name)) is not None:
```

But you don't need `is not None` here anyway. Matches are truthy and None is falsey. So you just need:

```
if m := re.match(f'^.+(\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d\d\d)$', name):
```

(Arguably it's better practice to use `()` whenever you're using an assignment expression, to make clear what's being assigned.)

See [PEP572#Relative precedence of :=](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#relative-precedence-of)